# JVM Core Dump "_thread_blocked" normal?

Tags: java, crash, jvm

I have a JVM app that is randomly crashing and none of the developers are that great with analyzing Java apps (the irony). When pouring through the output I'm seeing tons of threads with the state `_thread_blocked`. Is this normal?

The behavior we're seeing is the app will come up and stay up for an indeterminate amount of time -- anywhere from 10 minutes to like 6 hours -- then it will quit unexpectedly (usually via a SIGSEV), however there is nothing in the app logs, system logs, `dmesg`, `mail`, or any of the other nooks and crannies linux likes to put messages. There's just nothing execpt a core dump.

I've posted a portion of the core dump below (the whole thing is too large for SO) and a link to the full dump. If anyone has any ideas I'm open to them.

FULL DUMP: https://gist.github.com/peterfraedrich/f01b99308f402c8b8bc676fa0d404707

```
...
  0x00007f18586ba800 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-504" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5443, stack(0x00007f1819e1b000,0x00007f1819f1c000)]
  0x00007f1858525000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-503" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5442, stack(0x00007f1817cfa000,0x00007f1817dfb000)]
  0x00007f18585e1000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-502" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3377, stack(0x00007f18261da000,0x00007f18262db000)]
  0x00007f1858657000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-501" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3371, stack(0x00007f1818e0b000,0x00007f1818f0c000)]
  0x00007f18589e3000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-499" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28208, stack(0x00007f1817af8000,0x00007f1817bf9000)]
  0x00007f18585d6000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-493" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28202, stack(0x00007f18365be000,0x00007f18366bf000)]
  0x00007f1858658800 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-492" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28201, stack(0x00007f1818c09000,0x00007f1818d0a000)]
  0x00007f185867b800 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-490" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28191, stack(0x00007f1816fed000,0x00007f18170ee000)]
  0x00007f1858549000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-489" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28190, stack(0x00007f18161df000,0x00007f18162e0000)]
  0x00007f1858357000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-488" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28189, stack(0x00007f18179f7000,0x00007f1817af8000)]
  0x00007f1858374800 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-487" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28188, stack(0x00007f1835db6000,0x00007f1835eb7000)]
  0x00007f1858348800 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-486" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28187, stack(0x00007f1816be9000,0x00007f1816cea000)]
  0x00007f18588b2000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-485" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28186, stack(0x00007f18172f0000,0x00007f18173f1000)]
  0x00007f18586b8800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27731, stack(0x00007f1818b08000,0x00007f1818c09000)]
  0x00007f1840016800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27681, stack(0x00007f18180fe000,0x00007f18181ff000)]
  0x00007f1854b22800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26853, stack(0x00007f1819714000,0x00007f1819815000)]
  0x00007f185834a800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26659, stack(0x00007f1818a07000,0x00007f1818b08000)]
  0x00007f183c1bf000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26632, stack(0x00007f18174f2000,0x00007f18175f3000)]
  0x00007f1850739000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26601, stack(0x00007f1816eec000,0x00007f1816fed000)]
  0x00007f185056e000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26534, stack(0x00007f18165e3000,0x00007f18166e4000)]
  0x00007f1858840000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-484" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23325, stack(0x00007f18349a2000,0x00007f1834aa3000)]
  0x00007f1858480800 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-479" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23320, stack(0x00007f1816deb000,0x00007f1816eec000)]
  0x00007f18582c4000 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-476" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23317, stack(0x00007f181b12c000,0x00007f181b22d000)]
  0x00007f18589e6800 JavaThread "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-467" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10403, stack(0x00007f18170ee000,0x00007f18171ef000)]
  0x00007f1850f73800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10245, stack(0x00007f18160de000,0x00007f18161df000)]
  0x00007f18480ae800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32197, stack(0x00007f1819b18000,0x00007f1819c19000)]
  0x00007f18583ee800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31283, stack(0x00007f1818805000,0x00007f1818906000)]
  0x00007f185004e000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30765, stack(0x00007f181a21f000,0x00007f181a320000)]
  0x00007f183c1be800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30705, stack(0x00007f181e25d000,0x00007f181e35e000)]
  0x00007f183c436000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30447, stack(0x00007f1818d0a000,0x00007f1818e0b000)]
  0x00007f1848487800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30342, stack(0x00007f18169e7000,0x00007f1816ae8000)]
  0x00007f1850ede800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30002, stack(0x00007f181e05b000,0x00007f181e15c000)]
  0x00007f1850e90000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29934, stack(0x00007f1834ea7000,0x00007f1834fa8000)]
  0x00007f18480dc800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26682, stack(0x00007f18162e0000,0x00007f18163e1000)]
  0x0000000001dd0000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26633, stack(0x00007f1818603000,0x00007f1818704000)]
  0x0000000001dcf800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26614, stack(0x00007f1818704000,0x00007f1818805000)]
  0x00007f18583c4800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5988, stack(0x00007f18176f4000,0x00007f18177f5000)]
  0x00007f1850b3b800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4533, stack(0x00007f1817dfb000,0x00007f1817efc000)]
  0x00007f18558be000 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4495, stack(0x00007f181a825000,0x00007f181a926000)]
  0x00007f185819d800 JavaThread "hystrix-[redacted]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4493, stack(0x00007f181920f000,0x00007f1819310000)]
...
```

Comment: Yes, this is normal. What is *not* normal is the JDK version you use. 8u25 is a way too old, it is known to have bugs like the one you've posted.